# Progressive encroachment

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for progressively encroaching on someone's place/progressively abusing someone's hospitality. Or the intention there-of?

E.g. I start by asking for sugar and upon finding that you're helpful, ask for your house for a few days..

There is an implication of the party doing so being cunning.

While I've put some constraints (about being cunning etc), this question can serve as a compendium for similar idioms without such constraints too so feel free to answer. E.g. something like this being done with an altruistic intention, like a parent gradually entering the life of an estranged child to guide him.

PS: I tried searching but couldn't find much.

Comment: The [*camel's nose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel%27s_nose) might be of interest. A more prosaic idiom is [*the thin end of the wedge*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thin_end_of_the_wedge). Or the more exasperated [*give someone an inch and they'll take a mile*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-someone-an-inch-and-they-ll-take-a-mile).

Comment: Actually, this question can't serve as a compendium. That's "too broad". You need to be able to select a single answer which exactly matches your requirements: please narrow down what you need (or remove from the question what you don't need).

Comment: @Lawrence great answers, thank you. Just what I was looking for, thrice over :). If you write them as a formal answer, I may choose it as such (after other responses have come in..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *camel's nose* is a picturesque equivalent.

> The camel's nose is a metaphor for a situation where the permitting of a small, seemingly innocuous act will open the door for larger, clearly undesirable actions.
>
> According to Geoffrey Nunberg, the image entered the English language in the middle of the 19th century. An early example is a fable printed in 1858 in which an Arab miller allows a camel to stick its nose into his bedroom, then other parts of its body, until the camel is entirely inside and refuses to leave. Lydia Sigourney wrote another version, a widely reprinted poem for children, in which the camel enters a shop because the workman does not forbid it at any stage.
>
> [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel%27s_nose)

In change-for-the-worse scenarios, particularly with regard to politics or institutions, some might object to a seemingly innocuous change by calling it the *thin edge of the wedge*.

> (idiomatic) Something that if allowed or accepted to a small degree would lead to systematic encroachment.
> *The MP told parliament that legalising cannabis would be the thin end of the wedge.*
> [- Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thin_end_of_the_wedge)

For more personal matters such as your *sugar* to *house* example, one might mutter, "*Give someone an inch and they'll take a mile*".

> said about someone who has been given a small amount of power or freedom to do something, and then has tried to get a lot more
> [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-someone-an-inch-and-they-ll-take-a-mile)